# Failed to format SD Card

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted, sd-card

I'm having problem with my SD Card. I want to write an image file to my SD Card with `etcher`, but unfortunately it was interrupted by accident. Now I can't format it anywhere. First I used SD Formatter in Windows, but it failed. I use `diskpart` but I got error. And then I tried to use my `Ubuntu` to check the SD Card. It mounted in `sdc` with `unknown` partition type and content. I tried to make a new partition, but I got this error:

```
Error formatting volume
Error synchronizing after formatting with type 'ntfs': Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark,0)
```

and also sometimes

```
Error formatting volume
Error setting partition type after formatting: Error setting partition type on /dev/sdc1: Process reported exit code 1: sfdisk: --id is deprecated in favour of --part-type
sfdisk: /dev/sdc: partition 1: partition is unused (udisks-error-quark,0)
```

All the partition I made was failed and the fs type can't be read by the system (see `sdc`)

```
MODEL                      NAME        FSTYPE  LABEL    MOUNTPOINT          SIZE
                           loop0       squashf          /snap/gnome-chara  14,8M
                           loop1       squashf          /snap/core18/1705    55M
                           loop2       squashf          /snap/gnome-logs/   956K
                           loop3       squashf          /snap/gnome-syste   3,7M
                           loop4       squashf          /snap/spotify/41  163,7M
                           loop5       squashf          /snap/gtk-common-  48,3M
                           loop6       squashf          /snap/core/8689    91,4M
                           loop7       squashf          /snap/core/8592    91,3M
                           loop8       squashf          /snap/core18/1668  54,7M
                           loop9       squashf          /snap/gnome-calcu   4,3M
                           loop10      squashf          /snap/gnome-syste   3,7M
                           loop11      squashf          /snap/gnome-3-28- 149,9M
                           loop12      squashf          /snap/pycharm-com 347,9M
                           loop13      squashf          /snap/gnome-calcu   4,2M
                           loop14      squashf          /snap/gnome-chara  14,8M
                           loop15      squashf          /snap/gtk-common-  44,9M
                           loop16      squashf          /snap/gnome-3-28- 160,2M
                           loop17      squashf          /snap/gnome-logs/   956K
                           loop18      squashf          /snap/pycharm-com   348M
ST1000LX015-1U71           sda                                            931,5G
                           └─sda1      ntfs    DATA     /media/user/DAT 931,5G
SSD PLUS 480               sdb                                            447,1G
                           └─sdb1      ext4             /                 447,1G
SD Card Reader             sdc                                               30G
                           └─sdc1                                            30G
```

I also tried other partition types, but I got similar errors. I also tried `gparted`. It said that my SD Card is unallocated. And when I added a new partition, any type, I got errors like

```
Assertion (ped_partition_is_active (part)) at ../../libparted/disk.c:1417 in function ped_partition_is_flag_available() failed.
```

I also tried to Low Level Format my SD Card but it didn't work as well. Is there anything I can do with this SD Card?

Additional Information:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 30 GiB, 32227983360 bytes, 62945280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7c8d16bf
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to manually overwrite the first 512 byte of `/dev/sdc` by executing `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1 ; sudo sync`. Please make sure, that `/dev/sdc` is the correct device before executing the `dd` command. This should leave you with an emtpy SD-Card which you should be able to format, etc.